# Need expertise in controlling precision across calculations: specific case - elementary symmetric functions

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I've seen several questions here concerning precision issues when performing multiple floating point calculations, but unfortunately got completely confused. I really don't understand what precision means. Actually I don't even understand difference between accuracy and precision in Mathematica. And I badly need this understanding. I really hope somebody can explain all this to me, or point to an answer to a question where it is clearly written.

I thought maybe I would understand better if explained on my own example where I want to achieve precise result and cannot.

So, I need to compute some expressions involving $n$th elementary symmetric function in $2n$ real numbers, for $n$ around 50. The initial numbers are of magnitude $\pm10$ and are rounded to $.001$, and I need the output also up to $.001$. I am using Newton's formulæ: for, say, $x_1$, ..., $x_{100}$ I first compute $p_k=x_1^k+...+x_{100}^k$, $k=1,2,...$, and then recursively find
$$
e_j=\frac1j(p_1e_{j-1}-p_2e_{j-2}+p_3e_{j-3}-...)
$$
starting from $e_0=1$ and going up to $e_{50}$. I seem to lose precision catastrophically, since the final expressions where I have to use the $e_{50}$ must be between 0 and 1 while I sometimes obtain something above $10^{25}$ and sometimes something negative.

So, what is the correct way to calculate $e_{50}$ correctly to $.001$ in this situation?

And it would be really great if the answer would reveal some general principle for dealing with similar calculations, since obviously there is a general issue of this kind which does not involve specifics of my case at all.

Comment: To clarify: all you have are the power sums, and you need to convert them to elementary symmetric polynomials? If you have the arguments themselves, then use `SymmetricPolynomial[]` directly. (In general, Newton-Girard is not very numerically reliable, so you need very high precision if you don't have exact numbers.)

Comment: @J.M. I tried this, maybe I do something wrong but I got the message `Cannot create a polynomial with 100891344545564193334812497256 terms`. As for power sums - maybe I lose precision already finding them too, I don't know. I have the $x$es and I need their elementary symmetric functions

Comment: Hmm, yes, `SymmetricPolynomial[50, RandomReal[1, 100]]` fails; I haven't looked at it in a while, but I'm not sure why there's this limitation. Can you try `SeriesCoefficient[Product[c t - 1, {c, xlist}], {t, 0, 50}]`, please?

Comment: @J.M. WOOOOW that works! (Well I switched to `c t + 1` not to care about signs but woow!) Could you make this an answer? Can you explain why this particular method was optimal here?

Comment: If you don't mind a bit of a wait, I'll write one later; I've got something running...

Comment: Sure sorry anytime you want! I am already using your method, seems to be very precise.

Comment: Various ways of calculating elementary symmetric polynomial can be found in: [Finding column with maximum sum of by-element products of column subsets efficiently?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127214/14303)

Comment: @jkuczm Indeed, many thanks for pointing this out!